# Using Java stream to filter a list and create a map

Tags: java, stream

In `List<Hotel>`, I'd like to extract `Hotel`s which has `OTAProperty` with a specific `otaName`, as `Map<Long, Hotel>`. The map's key is the `id` for the `OTAProperty` named given `otaName`, and the value for the map is the `Hotel` instance.

I made a method `createHotelMapByOtaName` working as intended. But I think it's possible to remove nested `forEach` block by using Java 8's stream and related operations such as `map`, `flatMap`, and `Collectors.toMap`. Can anyone get some advice or code snippets?

```
package com.example;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class HotelService {

    public static Map<Long, Hotel> createHotelMapByOtaName(List<Hotel> hotels, String otaName) {
        Map<Long, Hotel> map = new HashMap<>();
        hotels.forEach(h -> {
            h.getOtaProperties().forEach(op -> {
                if (otaName.equals(op.getOtaName())) map.put(op.getId(), h);
            });
        });
        return map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Hotel> hotels = Lists.newArrayList(
                new Hotel("Hilton",
                        Lists.newArrayList(
                                new OTAProperty(1L, "expedia"),
                                new OTAProperty(2L, "agoda"))),
                new Hotel("Ramada",
                        Lists.newArrayList(
                                new OTAProperty(4L, "agoda"))),
                new Hotel("Hyatt",
                        Lists.newArrayList(
                                new OTAProperty(5L, "expedia")))
        );
        // expected: {1=Hotel{name=Hilton, otaProperties=[OTAProperty{id=1, otaName=expedia}, OTAProperty{id=2, otaName=agoda}]}, 5=Hotel{name=Hyatt, otaProperties=[OTAProperty{id=5, otaName=expedia}]}}
        System.out.println(HotelService.createHotelMapByOtaName(hotels, "expedia"));
    }
}
```

Followings are codes for 2 models:

`Hotel.java`:

```
package com.example;

import com.google.common.base.MoreObjects;

import java.util.List;

public class Hotel {
    private String name;
    private List<OTAProperty> otaProperties;

    public Hotel(String name, List<OTAProperty> otaProperties) {
        this.name = name;
        this.otaProperties = otaProperties;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<OTAProperty> getOtaProperties() {
        return otaProperties;
    }

    public void setOtaProperties(List<OTAProperty> otaProperties) {
        this.otaProperties = otaProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("name", name)
                .add("otaProperties", otaProperties)
                .toString();
    }
}
```

`OTAProperty.java`:

```
package com.example;

import com.google.common.base.MoreObjects;

public class OTAProperty {
    private Long id;
    private String otaName;

    public OTAProperty(Long id, String otaName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.otaName = otaName;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getOtaName() {
        return otaName;
    }

    public void setOtaName(String otaName) {
        this.otaName = otaName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("id", id)
                .add("otaName", otaName)
                .toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This transformation is not so obvious, but still feasible without instantiating a dedicated `Map` directly and without using `forEach`.

First of all, I suggest to implement `hashCode` and `equals` in `Hotel` and `OTAProperty` classes: this is often useful, especially when storing objects in collections.

Here is how the functional sequence can look like:

```
public static Map<Long, Hotel> createHotelMapByOtaName2(List<Hotel> hotels, String otaName) {
  return hotels.stream()
             .map(hotel ->
                hotel.getOtaProperties().stream()
                     .filter(op -> otaName.equals(op.getOtaName())) // 1
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(OTAProperty::getId,  
                                               (h) -> hotel))) // 2
             .map(Map::entrySet) // 3
             .flatMap(Collection::stream) // 4
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                       Map.Entry::getValue)); // 5
}
```

1. Equivalent of the original `if` condition: we take only `OTAProperties` that match the required name.
2. Each `hotel` item is wrapped to a `Map<Long, Hotel>`, which is a subset of the resulting map.
3. Transformation of the stream of Maps into a stream of `Set<Entry<Long, Hotel>>`.
4. Concatenation of streams of Sets into a single stream of `Entry<Long, Hotel>`. Unfortunately, we cannot join `Map`s so easily, that is why there is this intermediate transformation.
5. Finally, the stream of entries is collected into a `Map` representing the result of the sequence.